# Обработчик ввода текста в ячейку таблицы jTable Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста как обработать событие при редактировании ячейки таблицы jTable . У меня есть таблица , 1 колонка редактируемая . Как можно обработать событие когда пользователь захочет отредактировать ячейку , а точнее KeyPress событие . Для самой таблицы понятно как делать, а как для ячейки не могу додуматься .
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

А почему именно KeyPress? Чего бы не прикрутить Listener к CellEditor'у, если таковой назначен? Скажем, на перехват фокуса ввода. Только выбрал чтоб редактировать - вот тебе и событие. 
Еще вариант - попробовать назначить TableModelListener с методом tableChanged(), этот будет реагировать на любые изменения. Но уже после изменений

Answer (score 0):

Сопоставить координаты ячейки с данными массива (коллекции), например:

```
ListSelectionListener lsl = new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            return ;
        }

        int row = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex() ;
        int col = table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
        final Point p = new Point(-1, -1);
        boolean bo = false;
        if (p.x != row || p.y != col) {
            p.move(row, col);
            table.setValueAt(!bo, row, col);

            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }  
};

table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(lsl);
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(lsl);
```